# Import error when building .py file to .exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe, distutils, setup.py

I am using python 2.7.10, and have scripted a program which plays music with the help of mp3play module. I have installed the mp3play module and the program is working fine in .py format but when I am trying to build it into .exe with the help of py2exe, It is giving me ImportError: Stating mp3play module is not installed. Here is the following code for the setup.py file for the building of exe

```
import os
import sys
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

py2exe.build_exe._py_suffixes = ['.py', '.pyo', '.pyc', '.pyw', '.dat', '.log', '.txt', '.png']




setup(
   version = "1.0",            
   name = "abcd",
   author = "pqrs,mnop",
   author_email = "abcd@gmail.com,pqrs@gmail.com",
   windows=[{'script': "main.py","icon_resources": [(0, "data/icon.ico")]}] , options={'py2exe':{"skip_archive": True,"unbuffered": True,'packages':['Tkinter','PIL','mp3play','tkFileDialog','tkMessageBox','ttk','os', 'sys']}}
 )
```

can someone help me out and tell me where I am getting it wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

A very elegant way  of using mp3play can be refered from here http://mp3play.googlecode.com

Comment: Sorry to stay but my rpogram is working fine only that it is not building into exe